# Firebase rule base on path name

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

How to set a firebase rule, depenent on the path name?

**Example Path**

> /databases/(default)/_TEST_documents1

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents1 {
                 //match /{Xdocument=**} {
         //   allow read: if true;
         //   allow write: if true;
         //}

         match /_TEST_/{path=**} {
            allow read: if true;
            allow write: if true;
         }
     }
}
```

I have several path's with all the same pattern. What I want to know is, if I can setup a generic rule to not setup every path again individual.

Sample to optimize:

[image: Sample]

The question is how to generic the folder part. The requested question is not to give the whole `databases/{database}/documents1` full access.

Comment: I can't really tell what your rules are trying to express.  `/databases/{database}/documents1` is definitely wrong - there should be no "1" in that path.  The top-level match should not be modified at all.  It might be easier to explain how your collections work without trying to add any extra path information to them. Screenshots could be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I added a screenshot instead the text description now.